# Deisgn: Generic Elastic Search Index storing all Kafka Topics messages

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kibana, elastic-stack

Hi I am new to Elastic stack. This is basically a design based question. We have lot of Kafka Topics (>500) and each of them store json as data exchange format. Now we are planning to build a Kafka Consumer and dump all the records/jsons into a Single Index. We have some requirements but to begin with the most important one being, able to search through all the relevant jsons based on few important field values. For example if I have multiple jsons having field correlation id with a value XYZ, then if I enter XYZ then it should be able to search through all the topics.

Also as an additional question, since we are using Kibana do we have some inbuilt visualization for this search thing so that we dont need to build our own UI? This is simply for management searching specific values and need not be very fancy UI.

What should be the best thing to do, is having a single index the best design? What all things we need to consider? I read about the standard Analyzer and am wondering if that is enough for our purpose.
Assumption- All Kafka topics will store jsons and each json can be of different formats. Some might have lots of nesting, some might have nested objects. Some might be simple.

Comment: "Now we are planning to build a Kafka Consumer and dump all the records/jsons into a Single Index" - don't do this - use Kafka Connect :) https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch-video

Comment: Hi Robin, Kafka Connect is into consideration definitely but some access issues are going on with the support team which we are working upon. This query is mostly fom Elastic perspective. Thanks :)

Comment: I would avoid putting all topics into a single index. That'll slow performance for sure. Also, if you yourself are building the consumer, then that is all that Connect is. Whereever you would be running the consumer app, just run Connect instead, and it would be no different

Comment: @OneCricketeer, can we create kafka-connect cluster outside production cluster if we dont have put access to the servers to create connector-instances? Do we need to run our own kafka servers to do this? cant find any relevant examples.

Comment: @abhihello123 Kafka brokers and Kafka Connect are separate server processes. Not sure I understand the question. You should never run them on the same hardware

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yeah true but to start KafkaConnect I need to run `bin/connect-distributed.sh worker.properties` and running the connect-distributed.sh means Kafka needs to be installed on my VMs where I intend to run my Connect instances. But I don't have Kafka installed on those VMs, so it ultimately means I cannot run Kafka Connect  on the VMs where my Connect instances are running. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @abhi No, Kafka broker process doesn't need and should not be "installed" on the same machines as the brokers, as I said. Kafka Connect can/should be setup separately, for example, using Docker container cluster rather than VMs

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for your reply. This is for our office. We dont use containers. We have 3 VMs acting as application servers. Confluent Kafka is installed and managed by another team where we don't have direct access. I went through the documentation and in my scenario since we don't have Kafka installed in our application server VMs, I dont see anyway to run Connect instances on our App Server VMs since we don't have Kafka installed there. Let me know if you find my statement incorrect.

Comment: 1) Connect is standalone, and is extracted from the Apache Kafka package, not "installed". 2) "Confluent Kafka" doesn't exist as a product. The correct term is Confluent Platform... And I'm not sure what to tell you other than get more VMs